# what is the purpose of using caption in css?

Tags: css

The topic is about system fonts. what is the purpose of setting `button {font:caption;}`? [system-fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf9X9.png)

Comment: Not sure what the question is. As the book says, the purpose is to make it use the font that the operating system uses for its own buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks what is the purpose of setting `button {font:caption;}`

The system the user is on (normally a browser like Chrome or Safari together with their device's operating system and related storage) will itself have styles for various different items.

In this case the question is about 'caption' - when used as `font:caption` as above it is saying to the browser when you see a button element in my HTML please use the same font that you would use to show a button.

This means you can have a website which blends in with the look that the user is used to - buttons (and other things depending on what else you set) will look the same as system ones - in this case at least as far as the font goes.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font for information on what other in-built system formatting can be used.